# Dynamic change of content using radio buttons in pop up window

Tags: xhtml

I have 2 radio buttons. 1st named as Email and 2nd as SMS, so when i clicked on email it must show email input boxes and same thing goes for SMS.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one solution

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <style type="text/css">
        .hidden {
            display: none;
        }
    </style>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function showFields(id) {
            var emailFields = document.getElementById("emailFields");
            var smsFields = document.getElementById("smsFields");
            if (id == "email") {
                emailFields.style.display = "block";
                smsFields.style.display = "none";
            } else {
                smsFields.style.display = "block";
                emailFields.style.display = "none";
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<form action="#">
    <label>
        email
        <input name="selector" type="radio" id="email" onclick="showFields('email')">
    </label>
    <label>
        sms
        <input name="selector" type="radio" id="sms" onclick="showFields('sms')">
    </label>
    <fieldset class="hidden" id="emailFields">
        <legend>Email fields</legend>
        <input type="text" id="emailInput">
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset class="hidden" id="smsFields">
        <legend>SMS fields</legend>
        <input type="text" id="smsInput">
    </fieldset>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the javascript prompt here.

like

```
var varname=prompt("content ","default val");
```

refer [this](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_popup.asp)

or you can use `window.prompt()` refer [this](http://books.google.co.in/books?id=NLc_TQiWvo4C&pg=PA491&lpg=PA491&dq=xhtml%20input%20prompt%20for%20email%20address&source=bl&ots=TO1Uv4KDuD&sig=08vuVVAQ1K-8YZ1BSfaygpVfmmQ&hl=en&sa=X&ei=SRv4TuzhFoHZrQfO8OH_Dw&ved=0CFoQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=xhtml%20input%20prompt%20for%20email%20address&f=false)